# Error code 137 when running Cypress tests using cypress/included on Azure DevOps

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, cypress, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have created a suite of tests on Cypress and want to add them to a CI/CD pipeline using Azure DevOps. I have created a `.yml` file that uses the [cypress/included](https://hub.docker.com/r/cypress/included) docker image. When I run the pipeline, the containers appear to initialize correctly and the tests subsequently checkout correctly, however the actual test run immediately fails with error code 137. This error code usually suggests an out of memory issue, however I am not sure if it is actually that or just my configuration. Using `docker info`, I determined that there are around 7GB available in the container and the tests usually use around 1GB max. Additionally, I found that you can use `npx cypress verify` to ensure cypress is installed and working correctly, but that command itself fails immediately with error code 137, further suggesting that it may be my configuration.

My `.yml` file:

```
name: 'cypress-e2e-run-$(Date:yyyyMMdd)'
appendCommitMessageToRunName: false

trigger:
  none
  # branches:
  #   include:
  #     - main

parameters:
  - name: 'RunEnvironment'
    displayName: 'Test environment:'
    type: 'string'
    default: 'dev'
    values:
      - 'dev'
      - 'qa'

jobs:
- job: DockerInfo
  pool:
    vmImage: ubuntu-latest

  steps:
  - script: docker info

- job: CypressRun
  pool:
    vmImage: ubuntu-latest
  
  container:
    image: cypress/included:12.13.0
    options: --ipc=host --shm-size=1024M --memory=4g

  steps:
  - script: npx cypress verify
  - script: TZ=Etc/UTC cypress run -e CYPRESS_VIDEO=false -e DISABLE_GPU=true -e environment=dev -s cypress/e2e/mySpec.cy.js
    displayName: 'Run Cypress tests'
```

PS: I tried adding `options:` under `Container:` of `--ipc=host`, `--shm-size-1024M` and `--memory=4g` but the error was always the same. Additionally, the script itself does run in a docker container (I used podman) and the tests run without issue.